# "For" loops within a tkinter.messagebox?

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is the offending code:

```
import itertools

perms = itertools.product('AEIOU', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', '-', '0123456789', '0123456789', '0123456789')

print('The possible combinations are:')
for perm in perms:
    print(''.join(perm))
```

I am wanting to actually display this generated information in a GUI tkinter box, a small function within a program that has various other functions. I tried:

```
for perm in perms:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Results', \
        ''.join(perm))
```

...but this displays each possibility, one by one, each in invidivual windows. Is it possible to have the for loop function within the window, so it scrolls in the window? If not, is there a friendlier solution I should research to displaying all this info in a clean way?

Comment: That's going to be a lot of text. Do you really want to display 130000 lines to the user?

Comment: Not particularly. It is a school assignment that wants us to display that many lines in a single window. I am trying to spruce it up with buttons, smaller windows, and just a better appearance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to move your loop in a little bit.  This ought to do it:

```
tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Results', '\n'.join(''.join(perm) for perm in perms))
```

Comment: That creates a single dialog with a line for each combination.  It will likely run off the bottom of your screen and be nearly unusable, but it ought to _work_, kind of.